# Tor on htmlunit

Tags: java, curl, htmlunit, tor

I am trying to use `HtmlUnit` along with `Tor` to have multiple public addresses, to login and book some extra tickets in a website that keeps track of IP adresses through which tickets are booked. I run `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` on my machine, so far I found a way to run parallel instances of `Tor` by using the instructions from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/01_gpg/multiple-instance-of-tor). The code how ever successfully works fine when used in

> curl --proxy socks5h://localhost:9060 http://ipinfo.io/ip

and shows a valid proxy address. But when used in HtmlUnit like

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
    ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig("127.0.0.1", 9060, true);
    webClient.getOptions().setProxyConfig(proxyConfig);
    page = webClient.getPage("http://ipinfo.io/ip");
    System.out.println(page.asText());
```

shows some other address, which is not the same as shown in browser or as in using curl command, when hit using the same URL.

Note: curl and browser shows the same IP addresses.

Comment: Even without using any proxy, Web Client shows a different ip from that of the browser or curl.

Answer (score 0):

Try the port number 9150 instead of 9050.

Note: Tor uses 9050 and TBB uses 9150.